# difference between non-/ shared scopes

Tags: object-model, search-scope

can someone point out for me the difference between shared scopes and non-shared scopes?
I *think* one difference is that shared scopes are available in all site-collections, whereas non-shared scopes are only for one site-collection.

I have seen [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8601/sharepoint-2010-add-a-new-search-scope-programmatically) which shows how to programatically (means utilizing the object model) create a shared scope.
Is there a way to programatically create non-shared scopes?

Is there any suggested reading on sharepoint-seach for "noobs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two Scopes
1. Global - Created at the Search Service Application in 2010 or SSP in MOSS 2007
2. Local Scope - Created at the SiteCollection Level

Have a look at this [Link](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/04/creating-sharepoint-2010-search-scopes-programmatically/)